# Force TCP protocol on localhost in peewee

Tags: python, orm, peewee

Can I force peewee to use TCP protocol rather than using a unix socket when making a MySQL localhost connection? It seems like peewee is assuming it can use a unix socket when I ask for a connection to localhost.

The reason I need this is that the MySQL server is behind a firewall. I have ssh access to the MySQL server, but the MySQL port is closed. Therefore, I am using SSH to tunnel the MySQL port to the localhost port 3307 where I am running the python script with peewee.

My code looks like this now:

```
from playhouse.db_url import connect
from peewee import *

db_proxy = Proxy()

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db_proxy

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    id = BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ...

<more models...>

...

host = 'localhost'
port = 3307
url = 'mysql://%s:%s@%s:%d/%s' % (user, passwd, host, port, dbname)
db = connect(url)
db_proxy.initialize(db)

...

MyModel.create(id=...)
```

By the way, making a URL connection was my second attempt at this. Originally, I tried to initialize the database like this:

```
db = MySQLDatabase(dbname, **{'host': host, 'port': port, 'password': passwd, 'user': user})
db_proxy.initialize()
```

In both cases, the result was the same::

```
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3516, in __exit__
    return self._helper.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3546, in __exit__
    self.rollback(False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3531, in rollback
    self.db.rollback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3025, in rollback
    self.get_conn().rollback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 2964, in get_conn
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 2946, in connect
    self.initialize_connection(self.__local.conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 2864, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(*exc_value.args), traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 2944, in connect
    **self.connect_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3401, in _connect
    return mysql.connect(db=database, **conn_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question...

For host, use '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost'.

Peewee just passes the parameters to the MySQLdb module. Quoting from http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html:

> UNIX sockets and named pipes don't work over a network, so if you
>   specify a host other than localhost, TCP will be used, and you can
>   specify an odd port if you need to (the default port is 3306):
>
> db=_mysql.connect(host="outhouse",port=3307,passwd="moonpie",db="thangs")
>
> If you really had to, you could connect to the local host with TCP by
>   specifying the full host name, or 127.0.0.1.

Apparently MySQLdb ignores even an explicit port number if host='localhost'.